# definite article usage with president

Tags: definite-articles

What would be the correct sentence and why:

He is president of Finland?

or

He is the president of Finland?

Comment: Which have you come across? What are your thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 4):

It could  be either:

> He is President of Finland.

or

> He is the President/president of Finland.

The first refers to him by title. It is a true Proper Noun or name. The second is just a description of his job; it is akin to saying *he is the head chef/Head Chef*. They are both correct.